# insert millions of records into two mysql tables

Tags: java, mysql

I have 5 tables with me each with millions of lines in each table.

Each table has same format i.e. email, ip address, location. A single email address can be present in any of the five tables or in all of the 5 tables. And there are two other tables namely `User_ip` and `User_location`.

I want to store unique ip adress of each email address in User_ip table, and distinct location of each email address in user_location table.

Currently,  I have been following this procedure but this is taking alot of time. Is there any other solution or method???

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();

        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into temp(email,ip,location) select email,ip,location from Apr_web group by email,ip");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into temp(email,ip,location) select email,ip,location from Apr_gov group by email,ip");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into temp(email,ip,location) select email,ip,location from Apr_mail group by email,ip");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into temp(email,ip,location) select email,ip,location from Apr_pop group by email,ip");
        stmt.executeUpdate("insert into temp(email,ip,location) select email,ip,location from Apr_imap group by email,ip");

stmt1 = connection.createStatement();
stmt1.executeQuery("select distinct email from temp");
        ResultSet rs = stmt1.getResultSet();
        while(rs.next()){    
 Statement stmt2 = connection.createStatement();
                stmt2.executeQuery("select distinct substring_index(ip,'.',2) from temp where email='"+email+"'");
                ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.getResultSet();
                while(rs2.next()`enter code here`){
                    ip=rs2.getString(1);

                    Statement stmt3 = connection.createStatement();
                    Statement stmt4 = connection.createStatement();
                    stmt3.executeQuery("select * from user_ip where uid='"+email+"' and ip='"+ip+"'");
                    ResultSet rs3 = stmt3.getResultSet();
                    if(rs3.next()){
                        System.out.println("THE ROW ALREADY EXISTS IN IP TABLE");
                    }
                    else{
                        stmt4.executeUpdate("insert into user_ip(uid,ip) values('"+email+"','"+ip+"')");
                        System.out.println("ROW INSERTED IN USER_IP");
                    }

                }

 Statement stmt5 = connection.createStatement();                    
                stmt5.executeQuery("select distinct location from temp where   email='"+email+"' and location !='no information found'");
                ResultSet rs4 = stmt5.getResultSet();
                while(rs4.next()){
                    location = rs4.getString(1);
                    //Statement stmt6 = connection.createStatement();
                    //Statement stmt7 = connection.createStatement();

                    pst1 = connection.prepareStatement("select * from user_location where uid=? and location=?");
                    pst1.setString(1, email);
                    pst1.setString(2, location);



                    ResultSet rs5 = pst1.executeQuery();
                    if(rs5.next()){
                        System.out.println("THE ROW ALREADY EXISTS IN USER_LOCATION");
                    }
                    else{
                        pst2 = connection.prepareStatement("insert into user_location(uid,location) values(?,?)");
                        pst2.setString(1,email);
                        pst2.setString(2,location);
                        pst2.executeUpdate();

                        System.out.println("ROW INSERTED IN USER_LOCATION");
                    }
                }
}
```

Comment: Use powerful machine, split task into multiple threads and use batch when using jdbc.

Comment: What have you done to measure *what* causes the delay? Which part of your program takes the most time? How many rows total are in the 5 source tables; Do you mind losing the IP<->Location association? Do the user_location and user_ip tables already have data?

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos the insertion in the table User_ip and User_location is taking time. i am combining the 5 tables in table temp which has approx 1,24,00000 for the data of one month. and i want unique ip and unique location for each user so the assosiation does not matters that much. and i will do this procedure for 4 months, so i wanted to do it month wise. so after month both tables will be having data so i have to chck whether the ip and location exists or not..

Comment: @anonymous well, if you don't have indexes or unique contraints, of course it will take a long time. Also, for the love of everything that is holy, close your statements and result sets - or migrate to prepared queries...

Comment: @Tassos Bassoukos i do have indexs for ip,location and indexes. and this was the demo example.. in my actual code i have closed all of them..

Comment: With that many records and dealing with each individually I am not surprised it takes a while. That is potentially ~50m select statements and ~25m insert statements to be executed (if those ~12m records referred to ~12m separate users).

Comment: First you need to identify which part is slow. And just what 'slow' means. If your `INSERT ... SELECT` statements do not have proper indexes, they will be very slow. And queries inside nested loops also can be slow. If you have millions of rows you may want to look for a pure SQL solution to reduce overhead. Even then it could take minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will a solution like

```
stmt.executeUpdate(
  "INSERT INTO user_ip(uid,ip) "+
  "SELECT DISTINCT email,ip FROM temp "+
  "   LEFT JOIN user_id ON "+
  "      (temp.email = user_ip.email AND temp.ip = user_ip.ip) "+
  "    WHERE user_ip.email IS NULL");
```

work for you?

Explanation: Find the unique pairs of (email, ip) that are present in the temporary table but not already in table user_ip, then add them to user_ip.

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned auto-commit off? If not, when you create the connection turn off auto-commit by using the command:

Add `SET autocommit=0;` to the end of your connection String

Then at the end, when all items are added use the command:

`COMMIT;`

or is you want to discard all changes (if there was an error):

`ROLLBACK;`

These commands are sent to the MySQL db as a query to commit or rollback the data. This should allow you to put a lot of items into a table quicker.

Check the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) out for more details

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this in 2 SQL statements. Something like the following:-

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO user_ip (uid,ip)
SELECT DISTINCT email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2) FROM Apr_web
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2) FROM Apr_gov
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2) FROM Apr_mail
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2) FROM Apr_pop
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,SUBSTRING_INDEX(ip,'.',2) FROM Apr_imap


INSERT IGNORE INTO user_location(uid,location)
SELECT DISTINCT email,location FROM Apr_web
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,location FROM Apr_gov
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,location FROM Apr_mail 
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,location FROM Apr_pop
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT email,location FROM Apr_imap
```